# Real time data update with postgresql

Tags: python, database, postgresql, time, updates

I want to make multiple query in a database at the same time in same database with real time update. Like, google map the location of person update all time. Is it possible with postgresql?

Comment: I don't quite understand the exact problem. How can an update *not* be in real time?

Comment: Mainly how can i make multiple query same time in a database?

Comment: Just open several database connections and make several queries at the same time. I think you have to describe your problem/question in some more detail.